# How to access self.request.user in clean_avatar() in forms.py (django application)

Tags: python, django, forms

On a Django form, I'm getting my users to upload an avatar. I have a `clean_avatar` method associated to the relevant `ModelForm` in forms.py, where I'm doing some processing on the submitted avatar before uploading it. How do I access `self.request.user` in this `clean_avatar` method? I tried over-riding `__init__` of the `ModelForm` but goofed up.

For those interested, I want access `self.request.user` in the `clean_avatar` method in order to check whether the avatar being uploaded *now* is the same as the one the user submitted *just before this*. This will help me save bandwidth in cases where the form's being re-submitted (I've checked; in my app, re-submission causes the avatar to be re-submitted too, and re-processed).

The clean_avatar method currently looks like this:

```
def clean_avatar(self):
    image=self.cleaned_data.get("avatar")
    if image:
        try:
            if image.size > 1000000:
                return None
        except:
            pass
        image = Image.open(image)
        image = MakeThumbnail(image)
        return image
    else:
        return None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to pass it to your form as an extra parameter so that you could use it throughout form:

```
class FooForm(models.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # you take the user out of kwargs and store it as a class attribute
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_avatar(self):
        current_user = self.user
        # use current_user
```

Your views.py method:

```
def view(request):
    foo_form = FooForm(request.POST or None, user=request.user)
```

Comment: That's what I was trying, but can't get my head around how to access the form data within `clean_avatar` once I over-ride `self`. Would I do `self.form` then? I.e. `self.cleaned_data.get("avatar")` would become `self.form.cleaned_data.get("avatar")`?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question, where in your code did you override `self`?

Comment: Sorry, let me explain. Currently "self" in clean_avatar contains form data, using which I can access `self.cleaned_data.get("avatar")`. If I store `user` as a class attribute in `self`, then in `clean_avatar` would I still be able to do `self.cleaned_data.get("avatar")` without any ill effects?

Comment: Of course, django classes are python classes as well, there's nothing more common than defining a instance variables and use it in different methods of a class. If you are not familiar with python class and instance variables, please read this: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Comment: And btw, in `views.py`, I'm using a Class-Based `UpdateView` with the form I mentioned in the question. Thus, the views.py method you mention in your answer would, in my case, be to actually over-ride the `get_form` method, correct? As in, instead of `return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())` I do `return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs(), user=self.request.user)`

Comment: Actually no, I got more success from over-riding `def get_form_kwargs(self)` of the relevant CBV. Thanks again!